# C check if string looks template alike

Tags: c, regex, string

Hi I have got string which should look like `"   ab_dc-05:d5ef6:aef_    "`. I want to check if an other string looks like this (has 0 to x spaces in the start and 0 to x spaces in the end and inbetween there are only alphanumeric values and ":", "-", "_". What function should I use for this? Btw I found regex.h library but I probably can't include that one because I have to use c99 on Windows.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean something like [strcmp](http://ideone.com/x3MvMw)?

Comment: @Michi that would probably be too complex, if not impossible. `strchr()` / `strpbrk()`can be a closer match, but then also, some parser has to be added on own.

Comment: Why do you need to use a library function? A simple loop checking the contents of the array should suffice.

Comment: @Lundin yes I made that though it had so many while loops and ifs that I thought there'd have to be a nicer way. Ok I'll try those functions from string.h other guys mentioned :)

Comment: `regex.h` is a plain C header for regular expression library, you can use it freely.  See `regcomp(3)` and `regexec(3)` for documentation.  It is standard C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, something like this should work and it's perhaps easier than using an RE:

```
bool matchPattern(const char *s)
{
  // Zero or more spaces at the start.
  while(*s == ' ')
    ++s;
  const char * const os = s;
  while(isalnum((unsigned int) *s) || *s == ':' || *s == '-' || *s == '_')
    ++s;
  // If middle part was empty, fail.
  if(s == os)
    return false;
  // Zero or more spaces at the end.
  while(*s == ' ')
    ++s;
  // The string must end here, or we fail.
  return *s == '\0';
}
```

The above has not been tested but should at least suffice as inspiration.

Comment: Nope... It's always easier to use a regexp, as it only requires to use two functions.  But you have to know how to use them.  And the regexp library allows you to _extract_ the matched fields also....